# get a row from a many-to-many table on MySql from both primary keys

Tags: php, mysql

I have two main tables:

- Products
- Category

Then I have a 3rd many-to-many table called Prices with the rows:

```
   IdProducts  (Primary key and Foreign Key from Products)
   IdCategory  (Primary key and Foreign Key from Category)
   Price
```

The 3rd table doesn't have an individual ID for each row, just those 3 rows.

That said, I've already been able to insert data with no problems on the 3rd table using the data from Products and Category. Now I'm trying to edit this data in a small program but I just can't get if there is a coincidence to pre-fill the edit form. I'm using the following code:

```
$sql1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE (idProducts='$variable1' AND idCategory='$variable2') LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

$PriceCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);

if($productCount>0){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
       $priceshow= $row["price"];
       $idCategoryshow= $row["idCategory"];
       $idProductshow= $row["idProduct"];
     }
}
```

So with that I could get the price, category id, and product id ready to show in html.

I don't know if I'm doing something really wrong but my best bet is that the error is in the MySql query:

```
  "SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE (idProduct='$variable1' AND idCategory='$variable2') LIMIT 1"
```

This returns no values even if I send data that I know it should be using.
Is that how I'm supposed to try to get all the rows? Or maybe something like this can't be done and I need an individual ID for the prices?

EDIT: I found a dirty work around by sending the variables on a href Link... anyway Im facing the almost very same problem when trying to update the desired row, mysql code for update is this:

```
"UPDATE table3 SET (price1='$var1' AND price2='$var2') WHERE (price.idProduct='$idProduct' AND price.idCategory='$idCategory') "
```

and i recieve the following error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET (price='123231211.00' AND price='1212654.00') WHERE (table3.idProduct='QEW21' AND ta' at line 1

Comment: Your ids are numbers? Than try SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE idProduct= $variable1 AND idCategory= $variable2  LIMIT 1

Comment: I tried your same query in my local and its working fine.so check your connection.

Comment: seb my Ids are Varchar(5) both
Mathew thats weird, phpmyadmin returns me no coincidences.

I've found a workarround by sending the items via a href link anyway now im facing an almost identical problem... now I cant update the table with the modifications... im almost convinced that is the mysql code but I cant figure out how to do it and cant find examples to similar cases... Ill edit the question with the update mysql code Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: check this 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea7d3/1

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can go to sleep xd

```
"UPDATE table3 SET price1='$var1',  price2='$var2' WHERE
price.idProduct='$idProduct' AND price.idCategory='$idCategory'"
```

I was using `"SET(X AND Y)"` and `"WHERE(X AND Y)"` and checking the right uses of AND ends up it was actually like: `"SET X, Y" and "WHERE X AND Y"`